# How to fix a div on Mozilla - it's working correctly on Chrome

Tags: html, css

I have attached an image to my issue, what's happening is that Firefox gives my image an extra extension, where the entire thing works fine on Google Chrome, without the silly bottom image part. The image is set as part of a style, as a background image and the gray bit is defined with a table.

http://s8.postimage.org/rc26rtbr7/profile.png

Here's the style code...

```
div.frontpage_title {
    padding: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-image: url(../images/frontpage_tab.png);
    color: #fff;
}
```

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Seeing the HTML code would also be nice..

Comment: It looks like it's repeating, for a start you can add `background-repeat:no-repeat;` to stop that, although you'll still need to fix the height/padding/margin/something issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the hight of the div.

If the image is 20px high do, 
height:10px; /* 20px-5px-px (padding top and bottom) */

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that your title div has no set height.  This would mean that depending on how the browser renders the text, the height of the div would vary slightly.  You could fix this by setting a height on your div:

```
div.frontpage_title {

    height: 14px; // Set div height
    line-height: 14px; // Optional, will vertically center text

    padding: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-image: url(../images/frontpage_tab.png);
    color: #fff;
}
```

The "silly bottom image part" is your background repeating due to the extra height.  Your total height needs to match the height of the tab image.

Another option would be to make your tab image taller, by say 10px.  Then, if your tab is ever a little taller (<10px), you won't see the repeat.  You could set `background-repeat` to none, but this will simply mean you will have a gap instead of the repeating image.

Answer (score 0):

Stop the background repeating use:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

This will stop the image repeating, read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp)